# Cascading dropdownlist angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

im trying to get my second dropdownlist  to work, but cant figure out what is the problem. The first one is showing the data, byt the second is not working.

html:

```
<select class="form-control" 
   ng-options="option as option.label for option in myCtrl.options track by option._id" 
     ng-model="myCtrl.selected"></select>

<select ng-disabled="!myCtrl.selected" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="child in myCtrl.options">@{{child.childs}}</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var vm = this;
vm.options = {};

//get populate data for cascading options
$http.get("data/support.json").success(function(response){
    vm.options = response;
    vm.selected = vm.options[0];
});
```

support.json

```
  [{
    "_id": "1",
    "label": "Title 1",
    "childs": [
      "Title 1 - sub 1",
      "Title 1 - sub 2"    
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "label": "Title 2",
    "childs": [
      "Title 2 - sub 1",
      "Title 2 - sub 2" 
    ]
  }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one should be

```
<option ng-repeat="child in myCtrl.selected.childs">{{child}}</option>
```

If you are trying to display the children of the selected parent option.

---

Also, your first select can have its options simplified to

```
ng-options="option.label for option in myCtrl.options track by option._id"
```